# Adding a TimeSpan to a given DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I just want to add 1 day to a `DateTime`. So I wrote:

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime(2010, 4, 29, 10, 25, 00);
 TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);

 date.Add(t);

 Console.WriteLine("A day after the day: " + date.ToString());
```

I thought the result would be: `2010 04 30- 10:25:00` but I'm still getting the initial date.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values are **immutable**. The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) method returns a new [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value with the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) added.

This works:

```
Console.WriteLine("A day after the day: " + date.Add(t).ToString());
```

Answer (score 23):

You need to change a line:

```
date = date.Add(t);
```

Answer (score 14):

dtb is right about `DateTime` being immutable. Think of it this way: a `DateTime` is a value type, which puts it in the same category as `int` or `double`. Instances of these structures cannot be modified; they can only be evaluated and copied.

Consider this code:

```
int i = 4;

i + 2;     // does not compile, but what if it did?
           // would i become 6? clearly not --
           // i + 2 expresses a NEW value, which can
           // be copied somewhere

i = i + 2; // there we go -- that's better
```

This is analogous to:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);

d.Add(t);     // compiles (because AddDays is a function),
              // but is really the same as i + 2 above

d = d.Add(t); // that's better
```

By the way, one thing that might help make this clearer is realizing that the above line, `d = d.Add(t)`, is the same as `d = d + t`. And you wouldn't write `d + t` on its own line, just like you wouldn't write `i + 2` on its own line.

Comment: The real answer is always in the comments

Answer (score 7):

A DateTime is immutable, but the Add and Subtract functions return new DateTimes for you to use.

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

What is wrong with just doing `date = date.AddDays(1)`?

Comment: Still has the same problem - DateTimes are immutable :)

Comment: My Delta Time is a TimeSpan. So I can't use AddDays which takes an integer as a parameter.

Comment: @Amokrane, if your delta is a timespan I think you should rephrase the question title.

Comment: @Amokrane, the larger point remains. .Add(...) returns a new date, it doesn't modify the existing date. You still would use `date = date.Add(...`

Answer (score 5):

The result of date.Add(t) is what you're after:

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime(2010, 4, 29, 10, 25, 00);
 TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);

 // The change is here, setting date to be the *new* date produced by calling Add
 date = date.Add(t);

 Console.WriteLine("A day after the day: " + date.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date.Add(t);
```

returns a modified DateTime and does not change the original instance on which you call the Add method on.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime wont work if DateTime obj datatype is "DateTime?" which takes accepts null values, in such case `DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;`

```
        DateTime dateObj = new DateTime();

        dateObj = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString());

        var Month3 = dateObj.AddMonths(3);`
```