# cannot get a timespan to add to a datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I really have tried on this one, it seems so simple.

c#, using linq.

I have a linq query:

```
            var allNewStops = (from stops in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                           where stops.CustomerNo == 91000 && stops.StopSignature != "" && stops.ActualServiceDate == dateToCheck
                           select new
                           {
                               stopName = stops.StopName,
                               signature = stops.StopSignature,
                               customerRefNumber = stops.CustomerReference,
                               dateOfStop = stops.ActualServiceDate,
                               timeOfStop = stops.ActualArrivalTime

                           }).Distinct();
```

Which seems to work fine, I need the dateOfStop to be combined with the timeOfStop -- preferably in the query, but afterwards is fine also.

I have tried:

```
DateTime combined = stopinfo.dateOfStop.Add;
```

but Add states it is a unknown medthod of datetime

It does show what dateOfStop is a DateTime and timeOfStop is a TimeSpan.

I have tried about 4 dozen different combinations of everything I can think of.

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you!

Joe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737595/adding-a-timespan-to-a-given-datetime  did you take a look here already? (and are you sure that stopinfo is of type DateTime?

Comment: I don't see your "stopinfo" anywhere.. Do you mean "allNewStops"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw it seemed like you tried to use Add wrongly as Add needs a parameter (a parameterless version does not exist). That aside as I don't know the exact data layout I made sure to convert the variables explizitely in case they are objects, but if they are already of the appropriate datatype then they can be used without the (DateTime) and (TimeSpan):

```
        var allNewStops = (from stops in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                       where stops.CustomerNo == 91000 && stops.StopSignature != "" && stops.ActualServiceDate == dateToCheck select stops)
                       .AsEnumerable().Select(stops => new {     
                           stopName = stops.StopName,
                           signature = stops.StopSignature,
                           customerRefNumber = stops.CustomerReference,
                           dateOfStop = stops.ActualServiceDate,
                           timeOfStop = stops.ActualArrivalTime,
                           combinedStop = ((DateTime)stops.ActualServiceDate).Add((TimeSpan)stops.ActualArrivalTime)

                       }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Agreed, this is exactly what I did at first.  At runtime I get:  Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Add(System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If I run it without the added line, it runs fine.  If you inspect it it shows ActualServiceDate as a datetime and ActualArivaltime as a timespan.

Comment: I added more of my code, the line in the foreach part gives a compile time error:  Error 1 Non-invocable member 'AnonymousType#1.dateOfStop' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Ah I think I know what the problem is. You are directly accessing the database there and this means that linq tries to translate things into sql commands and thus it doesn't know most of the commands it normally would. There is a workaround for that though will edit the post there

Comment: I edited my code to show more but it is not showing up pending peer review...   :(

Comment: Edited it. AsEnumerable() is added before the select because this way it is translated into a list already and thus linq to entities does not interfere.  On another note MostlyLucid tnx for the additional info in the edit but if you want to show more parts of your original code editing your original question is a better way as that way  it confuses people less

Comment: @MostlyLucid you edited my code instead of yours that is why ;)
(corrected a small missing code in my example code added "select stops")

Comment: Thomas - that works!  However, it is extremely slow -- it seems to be going back to the database for every iteration.  Can I convert the entire thing to a memory list or something?    If so, I can try that and then open a new question if that is needed.

Comment: Better do a new question there (would also be interested in a better way to do this myself as I'm using similar constructs in my own programs). You could try to use ToList instead of AsEnumerable but not sure if it will make much of a difference or not.

Comment: I'll do that - I marked your solution as "solved" - I really appreciate the help.

Comment: BTW -- adding .ToList(); sped things up a lot.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime aNewDateTime = theOldDate.Add(aTimeSpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `dateOfStop` is from the type DateTime and `timeOfStop` is a TimeSpan, there should be no problem adding it like this:

```
DateTime combined = dateOfStop.Add(timeOfStop);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)` is called inside any `Linq` query while trying to get from the database, it will throw an error. As Thomas suggested, you can fetch all the results from the database before doing the projection, *or* you can use the `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime` function which tells EF how to safely translate your code to SQL. The following worked in my case:

```
Start = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
    g.ScheduledDate.Year,
    g.ScheduledDate.Month,
    g.ScheduledDate.Day,
    g.WorkFrom.Value.Hours,
    g.WorkFrom.Value.Minutes,
    g.WorkFrom.Value.Seconds
)
```

where `g.ScheduledDate` is `DateTime` and `g.WorkFrom` is `TimeSpan`